# jdb2 spike every hour for few seconds

Tags: mysql, performance, ubuntu-18.04, io

I get IO hang up every hour on the exact same time on my Ubuntu 18.04 server.
iotop indicate that jbd2 spike to araong 30% around this time.
The hangup last only few seconds.
I started noticing this when mysql_slow_query log also get filled up around this time.
I have no cron jobs running.

Ubuntu 18.04 in Linode server
mysql 5.7
apache 2.4
php 7.2

[iotop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgsQl.png)

[iotop 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpMZK.png)

Is there a Linux tool that can detect which program causes this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. It was caused CPU steal by a noisy neighbor in the server.
iostat 1 10 helped me debug the problem.